# I want to use a private obfs4 tor bridge, without tor

Tags: censorship, obfs4

I got my own server somewhere out there in the free internet, and I would like to connect to it via obfs4 and use it as proxy to circumvent local censorship. As far as I know, obfs4 requires a tor bridge. When I try to start it directly:

```
 [ERROR]: obfs4proxy - must be run as a managed transport
```

So now I have my private tor bridge, and can connect through this to the tor network. But actually, I do not need the "Tor" part of it ... I trust my server, and I would prefer higher speed and no restrictions on commercial servers because of a tor ip address.

Do I have to recompile the source to allow single SingleHop Connections?
How am I supposed to use obfs4 standalone?

**edit:** Can I use it, by just having a second server (maybe even a virtual machine) and forward the tor traffic through a "private tor network"?
Is obfs4 actually any better than scramblesuit for proxy purposes?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use it with Tor, because the bridge - after passing through OBFS4(and any pluggable transport) expects a `tor protocol`, it's not a transparent proxy

Answer (score 1):

`obfs4` does not have a standalone mode like `obfs3` does. It talks to Tor using the Pluggable Transport protocol [(specification)](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/pt-spec.txt), so to use it for something else you could write a program implementing that protocol.

Shameless plug: [I have written a Python 3 program that create a standalone tunnel from pluggable transports](https://github.com/twisteroidambassador/pluggabletransportadapter). The documentation still needs work, but the code is working. You will need Python 3 and the `obfs4proxy` binary for the server side, plus `rsocks` for the client side. Once set up, the client takes incoming TCP connections, obfuscates the traffic and sends it to the server, where the traffic is de-obfuscated and forwarded to your specified destination.